# Time Based Workflow triggering after record is deleted

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow, workflowrule

I though when a record is deleted, or no longer meets the criteria, the time dependent workflow queue removes the email reminder action from the queue

**Use Case**
I have a Time dependent Work Flow on the Lead object with following criteria

Lead Stage = 'Open'
Lead CreatedBy.Name ='Site User'

Action = Send email 7 days after created date.

Basically, if a Lead is open 7 days after the created date, send out an email to the lead owner.

**Issue**

I deleted the lead on the  5th day, after it was created, yet the email was sent to the Lead after 7th day from created date.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to replicate the issue and seems to be working as expected in my org.  As per [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=5) deleting a record that has pending actions removes the pending actions from the workflow queue. You can't restore the actions, even if you undelete the record. Salesforce evaluates time-based workflow on the organization’s time zone, not the user’s and users in different time zones might see differences in behavior.
You can [monitor](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.workflow_queue.htm&type=5#workflow_queue) pending workflow actions and check more details time-based workflow queue [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336120&type=1&mode=1).

Thanks